# rendering the image to pdf from views in django pisa

Tags: python, django, django-views

I'm trying to render the image to pdf. I'm getting the image from database and from views trying to send it to pdf through templates. Its coming up to the templates but not rendering to pdf

Comment: Is it possible to see some code?

Comment: VIEWS.PY                                                                                                     def take_candidate(request, id):
    data = Profile.objects.get(id=id)
    image = Image.objects.all().values()[0]
    template = get_template('letter/letter.html')
    print('after the template')
    context = {
        "name": data.first_name,
        "symbol":image
    }
    html = template.render(context)
    pdf = render_to_pdf('letter/letter.html', context)

Comment: UTILS.PY                                                                                                         def render_to_pdf(template_src, context_dict={}):
    template = get_template(template_src)
    html = template.render(context_dict)
    result = BytesIO()
    pdf = pisa.pisaDocument(BytesIO(html.encode("ISO-8859-1")), result)
    if not pdf.err:
        return HttpResponse(result.getvalue(), content_type='application/pdf')
    return None